# How to uniquely identify a webpage in javascript not using the URL

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, identity

I have a bit of an interesting situation.
I have an application that uses an MVC framework to deliver the view to the user.
This is great for the overall design perspective.

There is a wrinkle though.
At certain times a user could be doing something on a page and they would be required to go to another page to perform a look-up service.  I need to be able to uniquely identify each page that they go to and I am not able to use the URL, because all the subsequent pages that I visit from the parent page have the same URL.

Just an fyi, I care about this because I'm attempting to store the last known scrolling position on each page in cookies.

Example -

They are working on Page A.

They click a link from A and they are taken to page B.

On Page B they enter some values and click Search which will query a DB

A list of results is returned.

They can then select to "Return Value" of one of those search results.

The value is then returned to Page A.

When I run the following on each page (A and B) -

```
alert("${channelUrl}");
```

They are an exact match!

What else can I do to determine what page I am on within my javascript without resorting doing any sort of server side AJAX calls etc...?

Is what I am asking even possible?

Currently I am attempting to solve this problem by counting up the number of text fields on the page and appending that to my cookie name.  This is not ideal, especially if a user visits a page that happens to have the same number of text fields.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're not using GET or POST, how is the page delivered to the user?

Comment: can't you track through the  controllers in your framework that generate the different views? A simple javascript variable output to page, or class on body would help based on controller that creates output

Comment: @MikeRobinson - I just assumed that since the URL isn't changing.  But you're right, how else could it be being delivered?

Comment: Maybe attach a data attribute to some element common to all the pages, e.g. `$("body").data("pageA")`.

Comment: @Barmar - I went with your suggestion and added an hidden input text field in each of the screens that I visit.  On a new page load, I check if a certain input field exists and what it's value is.  It's a bit awkward, but it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

One common way to handle this sort of thing is to open the second page in a new window.  With this approach the parent and child windows know which is which (the child refers to parent as window.opener, and the parent refers to the child via the return value of the open call) so there's no need to manage URLs or anything to keep track.

Comment: Ah, but I need to save/restore the scroll positions from cookies. How do I distinguish Page A and Page B in the cookie?  My cookie for each page currently looks like this --- KulScrollPos_163=0,1345;  The 163 is the number of text input fields on the page.  I count this number each time I open a new page and look in the list of cookies to see if it exists.  If so, I read from it, else I do something else.

Comment: Well, if you open a new window, you never lose your scroll position in the old window; when you close the new window (after the user makes the selection) you'll be right back at the correct spot on the original page.

Answer (score 0):

People often use the part of the url after `#` to keep track of where you are under the a single URL. This is built-in supported with `<a href="#my-section">My Section</a>` which takes you to the element with id `"my-section"`, but you can use libraries that take control of this section of the URL in other ways.